# spring dependency for static nested class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Im trying to call a Class C method getID() from a static nested class by injecting spring dependency as follows:

A.java

```
package com.x

public class A{

    public static class B{
    C cref;
    public C getCref() { return cref;}

    public void setCref(C cref) {this.cref = cref;}

    public void method{ long ID = getCref().getID();}
    }
}
```

spring.xml

```
<bean id="b" class="com.x.A$B">
        <property name="cref" ref="cref"/>
    </bean>
```

I'm not able to get ID from Class C, please tell me if I'm missing anything.
Thank you!

Comment: For starters your assignment or method argument is wrong. `Cref` isn't `cref` so you are basically doing `this.cref=this.cref` and ignoring the injected vale.

Comment: Thanks for your response M. Deinum, sorry that was a typo I made while typing above, have corrected it here. In the actual code this typo is not there. Please let me know if you figure out why the code is not working.

Comment: And how are you testing you cannot get the Id? Also if this isn't the code then can you guarantee it is exactly the same as your actual code? There was 1 mistake already when writing down that piece of code, maybe there are more (that is always the problem if you don't share the actual code but a made up sample).

Comment: I debugged the code in eclipse to test. It is same as actual one, only class names changed

Comment: Again how are you testing this... Not interesting if you debug in eclipse. How are you testing in the `method` that you cannot get the id. What is your test looking like. You only provide partial information please be as complete as possible. So how is your xml file loaded and how do you get the instance of class B and test that it is not set.